# How to read JSON file with fetch() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I read local JSON file with fetch function in javascript?
I have JSON file with some dump data and one function which read JSON file on server.
For example :

```
readJson () {
   console.log(this)
   let vm = this
   // http://localhost:8080
   fetch('/Reading/api/file').then((response) => response.json()).then(json => {
       vm.users = json
       console.log(vm.users)
   }).catch(function () {
       vm.dataError = true
   })
}
```

So, What must to do to read local json file in this fetch function?

Comment: Side note: Your `fetch` call is missing a check on `response.ok`; this is such a common error I wrote up [a blog post about it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Answer (score 46):

> How can I read local JSON file with fetch function in javascript?

#### If you're trying to read `http://localhost:8080/Reading/api/file`

...then what you're doing is correct except you're missing the `.ok` check (this is such a common mistake I've written [a blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) about it). Also, since you're using arrow functions, you don't need to do `let vm = this;` unless you prefer it; arrow functions *close over* `this`. So:

```
readJson () {
   // http://localhost:8080
   fetch('/Reading/api/file')
   .then(response => {
       if (!response.ok) {
           throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
       }
       return response.json();
   })
   .then(json => {
       this.users = json;
       //console.log(this.users);
   })
   .catch(function () {
       this.dataError = true;
   })
}
```

It's important to remember that this is **asynchronous**; `readJson` returns before `this.users` has the value; it will get it *later*. If you want to know when it gets it, *return* the promise so calling code can use `then` on it:

```
readJson () {
   // http://localhost:8080
   return fetch('/Reading/api/file')
   // ...
```

More in the answers to these questions:

- [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [*Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

#### If you're trying to read `/Reading/api/file` from the file system

...then you can't, in at least some browsers, unless you serve the file via a web server process (as you appear to be serving the page. Then you read it via a URL on that server process as shown above.

To read a local file otherwise, the user has to identify the file, either by picking it in an `input type="file"` or dragging it into a dropzone. Then you'd read it via the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), not `fetch`.

Comment: The example makes it look like it's being served at `http://localhost:8080/Reading/api/file`, so I'm not sure this answer is applicable.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I **totally** missed that comment in the source, thanks. But it sound slike the OP may be hosting the *page* there, but trying to read a local file, not a file on the server.

Comment: Yea, it's certainly ambiguous. I have a hunch that this is a dupe of ["How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/497418).

Comment: @zzzzBov - Could well be. I've fixed the answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 20):

There is the very simple [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

you use it simply by:

```
// Replace ./data.json with your JSON feed
fetch('./data.json').then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  // Work with JSON data here
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  // Do something for an error here
});
```

Comment: Which is what they're doing, including the fact you're missing the `.ok` check just like the OP is.

Comment: they do not return the respone.json();

Comment: Yes, they do. They're using a [**concise** arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). That has an implicit `return`.

Comment: I want to read json file locally, or if I have to say exactly, must have a properties which say if propertie = true , then load local json file(with dump data) else load json data from tomcat server

Comment: I did it by forming url as explicitly localhost:3000/<path-inside-public-folder>. Worked!

Comment: This actually helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but fetching local jsons using fetch().then() doesn't work. Creating an async function and fetching that wat doesn't work neither.

The only way I made it is like this:

```
// dataList.json
[
  { "id": 1, "name": "Item 1" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Item 2" },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Item 3" },
  { "id": 4, "name": "Item 4" }
]

// react component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import jsonList from '../dataList.json'; // here I bring my jsonn file

export const App = () => {

    const [items, setItems] = useState(jsonList);

    console.log(items); // check that I have my array sored in my state

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Workin with json</h1>
        {/*here I can, for example, map my state*/}
        {items.map((item) => {
          <div>
            <p>ID: {item.id}</p>
            <p>NAME: {item.name} </p>
          </div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
}
```