# How to get json data using fetch in react

Tags: fetch

I'm using react and working on getting json files in the component.

I want to get the input.json file using fetch, but it's not data in the console. Why is this and how do I get the data?

input.json

```
{
    "formId": 1,
    "title": "from",
    "items": [{
      "itemId": 1,
      "title": "style",
      "formType": 1,
      "options": [{
        "id": 1,
        "text": "one"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "two"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "three"
      }]
    }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import inputData from './assets/input.json';

function App() {

  const getData = () => {
    fetch(inputData).then(response => {
               return response;
             }).then(data => {
               console.log(data);
             }).catch(err => {
               console.log(err)
             });
  }

  getData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Fetch</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

console.log[image]

Comment: please share your all code

Comment: How you exported your json in `input.json` file, as `default` export?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read JSON file with fetch() in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859358/how-to-read-json-file-with-fetch-in-javascript)

Comment: I'll check.
The problem seems to be that json file is not being exported. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing something in your result fetching, it should be

```
 fetch(inputData).then(response => {
            response.json().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with parsing response to json format?

something like this:

---

```html
import inputData from '../assets/input';

const getData = () => {
 fetch(inputData).then(response => {
const result = response.json()
            return result;
          }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          });
}
```

Comment: An error occurs when you perform response.json() because it is already a json file. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import inputData from './assets/input.json';

function App() {

  const getData = () => {
    fetch(inputData).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data);
              }) catch (err => console.log("err",err))
  }

  getData();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Fetch</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it's the same thing.