# Get data that's in the JSON but not in the table/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the information that is in the url but JavaScript returns to the [HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvf2O.png) "undefined". Does anyone have any idea what mistake I might be making.

If anyone knows how to fix the problem, let me know.

Get data that's in the JSON but not in the table/HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Request.css">
    
    <h2>Query</h2>
    
    <form id="form" method="GET">
        <label for="Year">Year:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year" autocomplete="off" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Year</td>
                <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="movie-table-body">
    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

FROM HERE Java-script

```
    <script>
    var form = document.getElementById("form")
    
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    
        evt.preventDefault();
        var year = document.getElementById("year").value
    
    
        let params = {
            "year": year,
        }
    
    
    
        let query = Object.keys(params)
            .map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k]))
            .join('&');
    
        let url = 'https://facebook.com=54s' + query;
    
        fetch(url)
        
            .then(data => data.text())
            .then((text) => {
                console.log('successful', text)
                let = tableHTML = ""
    
                for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    tableHTML += "<tr>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + text[i]["year"] + "</td>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + text[i]["data"] + "</td>";
    
                    tableHTML += "</tr>";
                };
    
                document.getElementById("movie-table-body").innerHTML = tableHTML;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
            })
    
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `data.json()` instead of `data.text()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read JSON file with fetch() in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51859358/283366)

Comment: Sorry @Phil as I said I'm new here, I just deleted the post.

Comment: @SBK: you did not "delete" the post, rather, you defaced your question, which is not allowed.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think OP might be getting mixed up. They posted an answer below that should have been an edit to the question which has been deleted. Don't know why they emptied their question though

Answer (score -1):

You receive a text, you must convert to JSON `data.json()`. Response from request is a object, so you can't iterate the object, you must iterate a array

```
let tableToHtml = ""
text[data].map(d => {tableToHtml += json.stringify(d)} )
```

If you want to add all keys in object, use for...in

```
for (b in data) {
tableToHtml += b;
}
```

Comment: I use `.map` but it's the same in you `for` loop

Comment: I get an error with the code you gave me. I attached the image for you to see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/93AGi.png @S.Wasta

Comment: Can you edit answer and paste "new" code, from my answer? Did you paste `text['data'].map...` inside second `then`?

Comment: It says "suggest edit is full" I don't know what that means. I think I can't edit your answer I think you can ask again with the correct code... @S.Wasta

Comment: I just attached the code below with what you told me to do. @S.Wasta